# Pass values to HTML elements from PHP in a different file

Tags: php, html, domdocument, wkhtmltopdf

I have an HTML file, and a PHP file.

In the html file i have specific elements with ids that i want to pass values to from PHP.
I can hardcode the whole HTML page in the php file and then use these values as i build the string but i'm looking for a smarter approach.

i know i can load the entire HTML file using:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile("filename.html");
$html_string = $doc->saveHTML();
```

But how would i go about assigning the values to the appropriate elements?
I am aware i can just look for the id's by searching the entire string and then appending those values, but i wonder if there is a different approach to this...

P.S -
The purpose of the whole thing is to pass the populated HTML into "wkhtmltopdf" if this helps..

Comment: you're looking for a templating system. There are a lot existing out there.

Answer (score 0):

You could either buffer your stuff (ob_start()) and then save it and call wkhtml2pdf or you could just a library that does the whole thing for you (i can really recommend this lib): https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 0):

I would populate the html with the values from the server itself using "data-xxx" attributes.

But you can also set a javascript array with the values you need to pass to the html and have separate javascript files, with jQuery perhaps, to fill in the html with the array's data upon page load.

This last approach is a simplification of how how Wordpress does it.